Data augmentation using GAN
I am using GAN for data augmentation of my HAR dataset. The issue I am facing is that my augmented data performance is very low when I test in my base modal.
The augmented data performance: train: 16% and test 15%
Original data performance: train: 94% and test : 91%
Mix original and augmented data: train: 51% and test: 50%
I have implemented generator and discriminator uing LSTM and batch normalization.
Any suggestion will be helpful.
Thanks
